# Can't update TexLive to 2020, but Update Repository is for 2020 Version

Tags: texlive, mac, update, repositories

Recently tried to update a package through TexLive, but I found out that the default repository for updates has switched to the 2020 version, while my TexLive is 2019. Unfortunately, when I went to try to update my TexLive to the most recent version, I'm told that the minimum requirements for MacOS is 10.13. I'm running Sierra 10.12, and it's probably all my computer can handle, it being a 2011 Air.

So, the question is: are any package repositories maintained for older versions of TexLive, and if so, how do I find these addresses? Do I have any options, or am I stuck with outdated TexLive, and outdated packages until I can get a new computer?

Comment: I think you can get it from here: http://www.tug.org/texlive/

Comment: MacTex has those requirements, but I think you can install TeX Live 2020 using the  [install-tl](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz) script by selecting the binaries for `x86_64-darwinlegacy`. According to the [documentation](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-unix-download.html) this should work for systems running Mac OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard) or newer.